# Syntax for setting draggablecursor property in google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to change the Draggablecursor for Google Maps to a custom image. I can set it to a name such as "crosshair" or "move" but I cannot get it to work with an image url. I tried every possible syntax I could google, including some which I thought were ridiculously wrong. Among them:

```
   var mapOptions = {
    ...
            draggableCursor: '../images/mapcursor.jpg',
            draggableCursor: 'url("../images/mapcursor.jpg")',
            draggableCursor: 'url(../images/mapcursor.jpg) 20 20, default' , 
            draggableCursor: 'url("http://www.blablabla.com/images/mapcursor.png")',
            draggableCursor:  url("http://www.blablabla.com/images/mapcursor.png") ,
    ... 
    };
```

The documentation merely states that it should be "The name or url of the cursor to display when mousing over a draggable map."  Can someone provide some guidance or pointers to what the exact syntax ought to be? Words like "default" in url are not known to me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a URL to a sample cursor? I believe browsers impose a limit on the image size (32px x 32px?).  Also JPEG is a strange file format to use.  The typical file format is a `.cur` file, followed by a `.png` file with transparency.  A JPEG will always have a background color, which will look odd.

Comment: I had tried .png too. Thanks anyway. The answer posted below worked. I am upvoting your comment anyway as there is some useful info there that I was not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to get it using external url like:

```
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        zoom: 8,
        draggableCursor: 'url(http://powerhut.co.uk/googlemaps/marker-images/image.png), crosshair',
    };
```

Instead of `crosshair` you can use `default, move...` as fallback.

See also [reported issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2874).

I expected that simple `draggableCursor: 'images/mycursor.png'` would work. Full path works:

```
        draggableCursor: 'url(file:///C:/Users/....../Google%20Maps/images/finish.png), crosshair',
```

and short path, too:

```
draggableCursor: 'url(images/finish.png), crosshair',
```

So, it seems that valid usage is:

```
draggableCursor: 'url(externalLink|fullPath|relativePath), fallbackCursor',
```

Comment: Jurkovic  It worked! Thanks for the precise syntax. The name after the URL is the fallback cursor - I was wondering what that was about. Thanks a LOT!