# Google Maps - GeoJSON.js - Replacing the Cursor

Tags: google-maps

I'm got a Google Map. I'm using the [GeoJSON.js](https://github.com/JasonSanford/geojson-google-maps) library to display polygons when the user mouseovers an area.  However this switches the cursor from crosshairs to the finger pointer.  How can I keep using the crosshair cursor?

I've defined the crosshair cursor in mapOptions:

```
draggableCursor: 'crosshair'
```

Do I need to set the polygon's clickable property to false as [a comment to this question implies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552790/google-maps-api-3-change-polygons-default-cursor)?  If so, how can I do this using GeoJSON.js?

[JusticeMap.org -- Website that I'm working on and having the issue](http://www.justicemap.org/t=gj0ew5)

Comment: I see the crosshair cursor when hovering over the map (in Firefox and Chrome)

Comment: You need to mouseover a polygon.  If you use the link above, you will have "Automatic Demographics" mode on. So that will draw polygon overlays as you move around the map. If you place your mouse over one of these - the cursor will change to the finger.

Comment: If you mean the shapes that go from light yellow to dark red (the "Black Percent"), then yes, I have mouseovered them and my cursor is the crosshair cursor. Which browser(s) are you testing with?

Comment: Chrome and Firefox.  When I move the mouse over the map, it outlines the polygon at that location with a thin black line and changes the shading of it.  Then the cursor changes to the pointing finger.  


If I turn off the Automatic Demographics - then I get the crosshair.

Comment: If you have automatic demographics on, and move the cursor really fast around the map - I see the crosshairs. But if the mouse stops, it gets replaced with the pointing finger.

Comment: I don't see any black outline or shading change when I mouse over a polygon; I get a `ReferenceError: showFeature is not defined` JS error (at index.php:824) when I mouse over, perhaps that is related?

Comment: Basically the same situation as @JefferyTo: I can't reproduce the error, as I don't see the outlines and I also see the `ReferenceError` in the js console. (Chrome 33.0)

Comment: I looked at your app and it appears this isn't related to GeoJSON in particular (I can't find a reference to the CSS/DOM cursor property in that project).  However,  I have noticed this behavior in google maps applications in general.  This question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835792/syntax-for-setting-draggablecursor-property-in-google-maps-api  appears to address the issue of customizing the 'draggable' cursor.  I Hope this helps, I could use the bounty :)

Comment: There is a wrong reference in the source code: `<script src='http://localhost/ejm/justice/geojson-google-maps-master/GeoJSON.js'></script>`. Please correct it and then we can try to solve your issue.

Comment: Oops!  That explains why nobody else has been seeing this bug.  Only I was loading the GeoJson library.  I've fixed the link now.

Comment: What you want to achieve is this: the cursor should remain crosshair when it overs an area. With **draggableCursor** you set (from the official Google Maps Javascript API V3 Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions) `The name or url of the cursor to display when mousing over a draggable map` so it is not what you want to do.

Comment: Is there another cursor option that I can set?

Comment: No, you should register to the Polygon events and change the cursor at your will. The link you wrote previously (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552790/google-maps-api-3-change-polygons-default-cursor) it's a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tries, the only way I found to do this is removing the clickable option from the polygon. To do this, find the **showFeature** function and add to the end this code:

```
function modifyPolygon(polygon){
  //TODO check if the parameter is really a polygon. maybe you can check an apposite flag to
  //choose between different polygons
  polygon.setOptions({clickable: false});
}

//Shows a feature - main function
function showFeature(geojson, clear, style){
  [...]
  modifyPolygon(currentFeature_or_Features);
}
```

Because you already set `draggableCursor: 'crosshair'` the cursor will remain crosshair over polygons also. I tested this with the code found on [GitHub](https://github.com/JasonSanford/geojson-google-maps) (using index.htm and GeoJSON.js) and it works.

Comment: While I accepted the answer, I'm actually having some problems implementing it.

I added
'modifyPolygon(currentFeature_or_Features);' to the last line in the showFeature() function.  And added the function. However it isn't working.

Comment: I tried these modifications with the index.htm example and the GeoJson Polygon. It still switches the cursor when I mouseover the polygon.

Comment: Solution is to replace the modifyPolygon(currentFeature_or_Features) with (currentFeature_or_Features[0]) - as I only have one shape in the array.  For an array, executing this for each element would also work.